# Firebird reading database issue on iis asp.net core 5

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, firebird, asp.net-core-5.0, firebird2.5, firebird-embedded

I want to develop a demo project in ASP.NET Core MVC with embedded Firebird v2.5. I read Firebird connection string information from a text file. Because I will change database in project presentation thus I must read from a text file. Or what is the your idea?

In this project I create a `DbContext` file and I fill in the database information using this class:

```
public class DbContext
{
    string startupdirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)+"\\settings.txt";
    string dblocation = string.Empty;
    string userName = string.Empty;
    string pass = string.Empty;
    int port = 0;
    string dataSource = string.Empty;
   
    public DbContext()
    {
        if (File.Exists(startupdirectory))
        {
            string[] allData = File.ReadAllLines(startupdirectory);
            dblocation = allData[0].ToString();
            userName = allData[1].ToString();
            pass = allData[2].ToString();
            port = Convert.ToInt32(allData[3].ToString());
            dataSource = allData[4].ToString();
        }
    }

    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        FbConnectionStringBuilder csb = new();
        csb.Database = dblocation;
        csb.DataSource = dataSource;
        csb.UserID = userName;
        csb.Password = pass;
        csb.ServerType = FbServerType.Default;
        csb.Port = port;
        //i added below code for embedded db
        csb.Dialect = 3;
        csb.Role = "";
        csb.ConnectionLifeTime = 15;
        csb.Pooling = true;
        csb.MinPoolSize = 0;
        csb.MaxPoolSize = 50;
        csb.PacketSize = 8192;
        return csb.ToString();
    }

    public FbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
        FbConnection connection = new();
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }

    public void KillConnection(FbConnection connection)
    {
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When I work locally, everything is fine. I can do all CRUD operations.

But when I upload my project, I see this screen:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> IscException: I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "C:\Firma\BlinePalmeWEB\Mandanten\11PalmeIT\GDI21.FDB"
>
> Error while trying to open file
>
> FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.GdsConnection.HandleResponseException(IResponse response)
>
> FbException: I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "C:\Firma\BlinePalmeWEB\Mandanten\11PalmeIT\GDI21.FDB"
>
> Error while trying to open file
> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
>
> IscException: I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "C:\Firma\BlinePalmeWEB\Mandanten\11PalmeIT\GDI21.FDB" Error while trying to open file
> FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.GdsConnection.HandleResponseException(IResponse response)
> FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ReadResponse()
> FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.Attach(DatabaseParameterBufferBase dpb, string database, byte[] cryptKey)
> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()

```
Show raw exception details
FbException: I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "C:\\Firma\\BlinePalmeWEB\\Mandanten\\11PalmeIT\\GDI21.FDB" Error while trying to open file
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open()
GDIWebApplication.Controllers.DbContext.GetConnection() in DbContext.cs
GDIWebApplication.Models.Deneme.ProductRepository.GetArtikelList() in ProductRepository.cs
GDIWebApplication.Controllers.ProductController.Index(string search) in ProductController.cs
lambda_method1(Closure , object , object[] )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException (0x80004005): I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "C:\\Firma\\BlinePalmeWEB\\Mandanten\\11PalmeIT\\GDI21.FDB"
Error while trying to open file
 ---> FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException: I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "C:\\Firma\\BlinePalmeWEB\\Mandanten\\11PalmeIT\\GDI21.FDB"
Error while trying to open file
   at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.GdsConnection.HandleResponseException(IResponse response)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ReadResponse()
   at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.Attach(DatabaseParameterBufferBase dpb, String database, Byte[] cryptKey)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open()
   at GDIWebApplication.Controllers.DbContext.GetConnection() in C:\Users\MD\source\repos\GDIWebApplication\Models\Context\DbContext.cs:line 60
   at GDIWebApplication.Models.Deneme.ProductRepository.GetArtikelList() in C:\Users\MD\source\repos\GDIWebApplication\Models\Repositories\ProductRepository.cs:line 20
   at GDIWebApplication.Controllers.ProductController.Index(String search) in C:\Users\MD\source\repos\GDIWebApplication\Controllers\ProductController.cs:line 16
   at lambda_method1(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I added all privileges is IIS but I can't make this work - how can I solve this?

Comment: use sysinternals Process Monitor to see which exactly file i/o attempts are done about the database and which exactly parameters are send to Windows and which exactly errors Windows returns.  Also, try first to make it work with notmal, stand-alone firebird, then switch to embedded. Standalone server would let you peek on your app work using tools like http://fbProfiler.sf.net

Comment: First of all, I apologize for my late reply. As Mark said, there was an error in the path of the db file. It's unbelievable, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using Firebird Embedded. As you specified `FbServerType.Default` (which is also the default value), you are connecting through a normal Firebird server using TCP/IP, and the error indicates that the database file does not exist (or possibly that the Firebird server process does not have sufficient access rights to open the file).

If you really want to use Firebird Embedded (which personally I think is not a good idea for a server application), you need to specify `FbServerType.Embedded`. Also make sure that the database file actually exists at `C:\Firma\BlinePalmeWEB\Mandanten\11PalmeIT\GDI21.FDB` on the server specified by `dataSource`.

Comment: First of all, I apologize for my late reply. As Mark said, there was an error in the path of the db file. It's unbelievable, how many days have I been struggling. thanks a lot.

Comment: @bykingpin that's why i suggested sysinternals Process Monitor  - it would clrearly expose it :-)